# Lync Server 2010 standard: issue sharing powerpoint slide

Tags: lync

I've installed Lync standard edition with: 1 front end server + 1 edge server. Lync web service running on 2nd NIC on front end server. When two external client (different LAN) trying to share a PPT slide: sender can see notification about uploading success and see the slide, another one  got an error:

> "This slide couldn't be downloaded.
>   Please contact...., Error reason: Name
>   not resolved"

. I'm trying to google but nothing found about this error. Another features: A/V conf, desktop sharing, whiteboard still works. I can see Lync connected to front end server but still have notification about not success sync corp address book. Any idea?

TIA,

giobuon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by doing these step:

1. Get right permission for share folder on front end.
2. Reconfigure DNS record for external-web (you can get its name from topo builder)
3. Open requirement ports.

One thing I got from this "days wasting" is RTFM :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the web sharing goes through the Reverse Proxy on your front end pool. External-web ports 4443 and 8080 on the server side, 443 and 80 on your router side. And yes it does need a public cert.

Glad you were able to figure it out!